# Force SSL in NodeJS / Bluemix

Tags: node.js, ssl, ibm-cloud

How do I force a NodeJS app to use https URL? I know the code and options. What my problem is that if I just go to http (desktop) - it will load some content (but shouldn't), but if it go to http on mobile, it doesn't load or forward to https.

Thus - my question:

If I only have https create server, no http - I'm not sure why it's even loading the non-https code...or why is it not forwarding to https?

```
https.createServer(options, app).listen(8000);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright - got it. I had visited http://www.tonyerwin.com/2014/09/redirecting-http-to-https-with-nodejs.html earlier, but made the obvious mistake of declaring it before I declared app.

Easy fix to my problem that was plaguing me for days.

```
app.enable('trust proxy');

// Add a handler to inspect the req.secure flag (see 
// http://expressjs.com/api#req.secure). This allows us 
// to know whether the request was via http or https.

app.use (function (req, res, next) {
    if (req.secure) {
            // request was via https, so do no special handling
            next();
    } else {
            // request was via http, so redirect to https
            res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
    }
});
```

Comment: This does not work in Bluemix due to the proxy server terminates the SSL and so all traffic will look like HTTP to your app

Answer (score 2):

On IBM Cloud (Bluemix) you should check the request headers as follows

```
// Check the request header
app.use (function (req, res, next) {
   if (req.headers && req.headers.$wssc === "https")
       {
        // request was via https, so do no special handling
        next();
    } else {
        // request was via http, so redirect to https or simply block
        console.log("Blocked unsecured request");
        // res.redirect('https://' + req.headers.host + req.url);
        res.status(403).send();
    }
});
```

Please be aware that the default `req.secure` does not work on bluemix because the Bluemix proxy server terminates the SSL and so all traffic will look like HTTP to your app. However, the proxy also adds a special HTTP header named $WSSC with a value of either http or https

Answer (score 1):

When your app runs in Bluemix, it is actually behind a proxy. The proxy is handling the request, whether http or https, and it forwards it to your app as http. So your app should only listen for http. If you want the external user to always use https, you can check the `X-Forwarded-Proto` or `$WSSC` headers in the request to see what protocol was originally used. If it was http, you can then send a redirect to https. But again, the https channel will end at the Bluemix proxy, and be relayed to your app as http.

Comment: Hi Marc - thanks - I'll work on that now. We have our certs uploaded to Bluemix - so that's all working with a cname forwarding ... everything needs to load under SSL for security.

Comment: To complement Marc's answer see this article: http://www.tonyerwin.com/2014/09/redirecting-http-to-https-with-nodejs.html